# Is there a way to have more controls/shortcuts displayed on the bottom of the window?

Tags: add-on, shortcut

blender 4.0 changed a bunch of button combinations/shortcuts.
Is it possible to have more than just the mouse controls displayed at the bottom of the window to make it easier to reference?
[image: image of what i'm talking about]
ty.

Comment: No, not really. In the _Preferences_ under _Keymap_ you can enable _Alt Click Tool Prompt_. This way in some editors which have a toolbar, click `Alt` will show some shortcuts in the _Status Bar_ at the bottom. However these are just a few, definitely not all and you cannot manually decide which ones you want to see there. Other than that the _Status Bar_ only shows optional shortcuts on the active tool.